# Super slow query with CROSS JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, cross-join

I have two tables named table_1 (1GB) and reference (250Mb).

When I query a cross join on reference it takes 16hours to update table_1 .. We changed the system files EXT3 for XFS but still it's taking 16hrs.. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG??

Here is the update/cross join query :

```
  mysql> UPDATE table_1 CROSS JOIN reference ON
  -> (table_1.start >= reference.txStart AND table_1.end <= reference.txEnd)
  -> SET table_1.name = reference.name;
  Query OK, 17311434 rows affected (16 hours 36 min 48.62 sec)
  Rows matched: 17311434  Changed: 17311434  Warnings: 0
```

Here is a show create table of table_1 and reference:

```
    CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
     `strand` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `chr` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `name2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     KEY `annot` (`start`,`end`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;


   CREATE TABLE `reference` (
     `bin` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `chrom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `strand` char(1) NOT NULL,
     `txStart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `txEnd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `cdsStart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `cdsEnd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `exonCount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `exonStarts` longblob NOT NULL,
     `exonEnds` longblob NOT NULL,
     `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `name2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `cdsStartStat` enum('none','unk','incmpl','cmpl') NOT NULL,
     `cdsEndStat` enum('none','unk','incmpl','cmpl') NOT NULL,
     `exonFrames` longblob NOT NULL,
      KEY `chrom` (`chrom`,`bin`),
      KEY `name` (`name`),
      KEY `name2` (`name2`),
      KEY `annot` (`txStart`,`txEnd`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Comment: The  tables do not have Primary Keys?

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT in your question title....

Comment: where did I shout in my question title??

Comment: Indeed the tables do not have Primary Keys because ... I'm still wondering if its really helpful to add Primary Keys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems with the `UPDATE` statement.

There is no index for the `End` fields. The compound indexes (`annot`) you have will be used only for the `start` fields in this query. You should add them as suggested by Emre:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_1` ADD INDEX ( `end` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `reference` ADD INDEX ( `txEnd` ) ;
```

Second, the `JOIN` may (and probably does) find many rows of table `reference` that are related to a row of `table_1`. So some (or all) rows of `table_1` that are updated, are updated many times. Check the result of this query, to see if it is the same as your updated rows count (`17311434`):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1
  WHERE EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM reference
      WHERE table_1.start >= reference.txStart
        AND table_1.`end` <= reference.txEnd
    )
```

There can be other ways to write this query but the lack of a `PRIMARY KEY` on both tables makes it harder. If you define a primary key on `table_1`, try this, replacing `id` with the primary key.

**Update**: No, do not try it on a table with 34M rows. Check the execution plan and try with smaller tables first.

```
UPDATE table_1 AS t1
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT t2.id
           , r.name
      FROM table_1 AS t2
        JOIN
          ( SELECT name, txStart, txEnd
            FROM reference
            GROUP BY txStart, txEnd
          ) AS r
          ON  t2.start >= r.txStart
          AND t2.`end` <= r.txEnd
      GROUP BY t2.id
    ) AS good
    ON good.id = t1.id
SET t1.name = good.name;
```

You can check the query plan by running EXPLAIN on the equivalent SELECT:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, good.name
FROM table_1 AS t1
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT t2.id
           , r.name
      FROM table_1 AS t2
        JOIN
          ( SELECT name, txStart, txEnd
            FROM reference
            GROUP BY txStart, txEnd
          ) AS r
          ON  t2.start >= r.txStart
          AND t2.`end` <= r.txEnd
      GROUP BY t2.id
    ) AS good
    ON good.id = t1.id ;
```

Comment: WOW Thanks a lot :) I added a column 'id' auto_increment primary key on both tables. From table_1 multiple rows can match the same name in 'reference' (800 rows in average). Let's say I run the UPDATE JOIN ON good.id = t1.id --> if 800 rows from table_1 matches one name in 'reference' that will update 800 times the column name in table_1, right ? :)

Comment: @madkitty: What does my `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE EXISTS ...` returns?

Comment: @madkitty: Did you add the two `end` indexes?

Comment: To answer your question, if 800 rows from table_1 match one name in 'reference', that will update **those 800 rows** in table_1.

Comment: yes I did added the two end indexes, I ran the query SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1
  WHERE EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM reference
      WHERE table_1.start >= reference.txStart
        AND table_1.`end` <= reference.txEnd
    ) --> I ran this 1 hour ago, it's still running.

Comment: @madkitty: Can you tell us what this query returns: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reference GROUP BY txStart, txEnd`. It's from the small table only, so it won't stall your db.

Answer (score 5):

You should index `table_1.start`, `reference.txStart`, `table_1.end` and `reference.txEnd` table fields:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_1` ADD INDEX ( `start` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `table_1` ADD INDEX ( `end` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `reference` ADD INDEX ( `txStart` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `reference` ADD INDEX ( `txEnd` ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross joins are Cartesian Products, which are probably one of the most computationally expensive things to compute (they don't scale well).

For each table T_i for i = 1 to n, the number of rows generated by crossing tables T_1 to T_n is the size of each table multiplied by the size of each other table, ie

> |T_1| * |T_2| * ... * |T_n|

Assuming each table has M rows, the resulting cost of computing the cross join is then

> M_1 * M_2 *...* M_n = O(M^n)

which is exponential in the number of tables involved in the join.

Comment: What you say it's true but in MySQL `a CROSS JOIN b ON join_condition` is equivalent to `a INNER JOIN b ON join_condition`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET
table_1.name = (
  select reference.name
  from reference
  where table_1.start >= reference.txStart
  and table_1.end <= reference.txEnd)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is equivalent?

Comment: The subquery may even return more than 1 row and raise error.

Comment: then OP's original query will also fail, no?

Comment: I think it won't fail but update `table_1` rows multiple times (once for every match) and that's one of the reasons it's slow.

Comment: I though my query was slow coz our data are two big.. table_1 has 34994288 rows and reference has 1560 rows. Maybe the design is wrong..

Comment: @Bohemian: mine doesn't fail it's just taking forever .. something likt 16hours T.T

Answer (score 0):

Somebody already offered you to add some indexes. But I think the best performance you may get with these two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`time` 
    ADD INDEX `reference_start_end` (`txStart` ASC, `txEnd` ASC),
    ADD INDEX `table_1_star_end` (`start` ASC, `end` ASC);
```

Only one of them will be used by MySQL query, but MySQL will decide which is more useful automatically.